# My laptop gets heated when I use ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, dual-boot, overheating

I have a Dell Inspiron 14z 5423. intel i5 3rd, 4GB ram, 32GB SSD. I use 2 OS on dual boot Windows 8 & Ubuntu 13.04. When I use Ubuntu my laptop gets heated, but that is not the case when I use Windows 8.

Why this happens?

Comment: Please, only one question per question. We could allow multiple question if they were all related, but here you need to answers.

Answer (score 1):

TLP is a good package to solve the heating problems in Ubuntu 13.04. It can be installed by following commands:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw smartmontools ethtool
```

For ThinkPads use  the following commands:

```
 sudo apt-get install tp-smapi-dkms acpi-call-tools tlp tlp-rdw smartmontools ethtool
```

Details regarding how to tweak TLP can be [seen here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681?s=0db3f141a9944a1784b3c2d1e02083bb)

Answer (score 0):

There are two major sources of heat in laptops: the cpu and the graphics card. Since your laptop does not have a dedicated graphics card, it is likely that your problem can be attributed to your cpu.

Fortunately, there are many good solutions for scaling back cpu energy usage (which will reduce the amount of heat generated and extend battery life!). This question has a very detailed answer that is likely what you are looking for: [Is there a power saving application similar to Jupiter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter)

Answer (score 0):

Please remove your linux swap partition from ubuntu from gparted and remove it from fstab.

After that you will never feel heating issues in ubuntu.

regards

Gowtham